# How to make a SQL to create a tag hierarchy based on items with the same tags?

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, tags, hierarchy

In my system I have items with some tags on each. Now I want to show to the user a tree with the tags. 
The tree should have all the tags at the first level.
Inside each first-level tag, should appear again all the tags that are found in items belonging also to the first-level tag.
In the third level, should appear tags belonging to the first and second level, and so on.
The idea is that the user could filter the items based on his tags and could refine the filtering entering in the tree without having to type the tags.

Items were initially stored as a string field in the items table but, to make this solution easily, I have moved them to a child table.

Using these items as input:

```
|Item       |Tags    |
|-----------|--------|
|Computer   |a,b,c   |
|Mouse      |a,c     |
|Keyboard   |c,d     |
|Monitor    |a,b     |
```

Should output this tree:

```
  Tree             Items that are show when selected

  root             Computer,Mouse,Keyboard,Monitor
    +--a           Computer,Mouse,Monitor
    |  +--b        Computer,Monitor
    |  |  +--c     Computer
    |  +--c        Computer,Mouse
    |     +--b     Computer
    +--b           Computer,Monitor
    |  +--a        Computer,Monitor
    |  |  +--c     Computer
    |  +--c        Computer
    |     +--a     Computer
    +--c           Computer,Mouse,Keyboard
    |  +--a        Computer,Mouse
    |  |  +--b     Computer
    |  +--b        Computer
    |  |  +--a     Computer
    |  +--d        Keyboard
    +--d           Keyboard
       +--c        Keyboard
```

This SQL should run only in Oracle database, so the use of `connect by` operators are acceptable.

I've picked this behaviour from the Delicious' Firefox extension, which show the tags in the form of a tree, but limiting it to have only two levels, and I need it to show so many levels as possible.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside : With 4 tags on 4 entities, you have 19 rows in your tree view.  With an large number of tags and/or entities, this will explode into an impossible to manage number.

Comment: Right. But I won't have a large number of tags, 50 at the maximum, and the items I will load them only when the tag be selected, so I think this is not a problem. But thank by the comment.

Answer (score 0):

*[Plz, forgive me for the SQL Server syntax... my Oracle skills are rusty and I had no server in hand]*

At the last decade I've faced this problem twice!

My solution:

1. Design a single table with recursive relation

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dummy(
     id        VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
     parent_id VARCHAR(128) NULL,
     --
     CONSTRAINT pk_dummy PRIMARY KEY(id),
     --
     CONSTRAINT fk_dummy_X_dummy
     FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES dummy(id)
   )
   ```
2. Design a denormalization table for pre-compute the hierarchy:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dummy_hierarchy(
     id        VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
     parent_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
     depth     INT NOT NULL
   )
   ```

   `dummy_hierarchy` has the properties:

   - `id` has a self relationship with `depth` value of '1'
   - `id` has a relationship whith its parent with `depth` value of '2'
   - `id` has a relationship with its grand parent with `depth` value of '3'
   - and so on ...

   Also:

   - from `id` one retrieves all predecessors, including `id` itself
   - from `parent_id` one retrieves all successors, including `parent_id` itself
3. Define a trigger on `dummy` that shall keep `dummy_hierarchy` up-to-date:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER tr_dummy_ins_upd_del
   ON dbo.dummy FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   AS
   BEGIN
     DELETE dummy
     FROM DELETED
     WHERE dummy.id = DELETED.id

     INSERT INTO dbo.dummy_hierarchy(
       id, parent_id, depth
     )
     SELECT id, id, 1
     FROM INSERTED

     WHILE 1 = 1
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.dummy_hierarchy(
         id, parent_id, depth
       )
       SELECT hie.id, par.parent_id, hie.depth + 1
       FROM
         INSERTED ins
           INNER JOIN(
             dbo.dummy_hierarchy hie
               INNER JOIN dummy par
               ON par.id = hie.parent_id
           )
           ON hie.id = ins.id
       WHERE par.parent_id IS NOT NULL
         --
         AND NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT id
               FROM dummy_hierarchy hie_par
               WHERE hie_par.id        = hie.id
                 AND hie_par.parent_id = par.parent_id
             )

       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
       BEGIN
         BREAK
       END
     END
   END
   ```

   As POC data:

   ```
   INSERT INTO dummy(id, parent_id) VALUES('COMPUTER', NULL)
   INSERT INTO dummy(id, parent_id) VALUES('MONITOR',  'COMPUTER')
   INSERT INTO dummy(id, parent_id) VALUES('MOUSE',    'MONITOR')
   INSERT INTO dummy(id, parent_id) VALUES('KEYBOARD', 'MONITOR')
   ```

   The query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.dummy_hierarchy hie
   WHERE parent_id = 'COMPUTER'
   ```

   Yelds:

   ```
       id        parent_id depth
       COMPUTER  COMPUTER  1
       MONITOR   COMPUTER  2
       MOUSE     COMPUTER  3
       KEYBOARD  COMPUTER  3
   ```

   This one:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.dummy_hierarchy hie
   WHERE parent_id = 'MONITOR'
   ```

   Yelds:

   ```
       id        parent_id depth
       MONITOR   MONITOR   1
       MOUSE     MONITOR   2
       KEYBOARD  MONITOR   2
   ```

   And, for back-tracking:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.dummy_hierarchy
   WHERE id = 'MOUSE'
   ```

   There's:

   ```
       id        parent_id depth
       MOUSE     MOUSE     1
       MOUSE     MONITOR   2
       MOUSE     COMPUTER  3
   ```

   Of course, this is not exactly what you need.

   But I wish to had offered some useful clues.